# What does <<2>> mean in an output? Double Less than or greater than signs

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages, syntax

An error in my output gives

[image]

I am trying to understand what the issue is. I was wondering if this <<2>> has anything to do with it, because I don't know what that syntax means. Is <<2>> just an ordinary number?

The expression $e^{Times[<<2>>]}$ also seems a bit weird to me but maybe this is equivalent to just $e^{2}$.

Obviously I am a bit new to Mathematica. Thanks for the assistance.

I will paste the offending For loop here in case it's relevant:

```
For[n = 0, n <= NN, n++,
  Print["starting q integration"];   
  q = NIntegrate[Abs[ψ[xx]]^2, {xx, L, L + 3}];
  Print["q=", q];
  AppendTo[probs, q];
  f = NIntegrate[
    Abs[P[xx] ψ[xx]]^2, {xx, -∞, ∞}];
  Print["f=", f];
  Pψ[x_] := (P[x] ψ[x])/f;
  ψ[x_] = 
   Integrate[Pψ[xx] SK[xx, x, Δt], {xx, -2, 5}] ;
  Print["Finished psi assignment"];
  ];
```

The output, up to but not including the error, is

```
starting q integration
q=7.61985 x 10^-24
f = 1.
Finished psi assignment
starting q integration
L is 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<<k>>` means that k elements have not been shown in the expression. The documentation for Short says : Short[expr] gives a "skeleton form" of expr, with omitted sequences of k elements indicated by `<<k>>`.